# Appending values to makefile variable dynamically

Tags: makefile

I am trying to generate this:

```
MYFLAGS += -DMYVAR0=$(MYVAR0)
MYFLAGS += -DMYVAR1=$(MYVAR2)
MYFLAGS += -DMYVAR2=$(MYVAR3)
```

I know how many MYVARs to append from a variable I have earlier $(NUM_VARS).
This is what I tried:

```
ITER := 0
while[ $(ITER) -lt $(NUM_VARS)];\
        do\
            MYFLAGS += -DMYVAR$(ITER)=$(MYVAR$(ITER));\
done
```

Can I use while loop this way to append?

Comment: Assuming you are using GNU Make, have you [read the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)? Like reading about [the `foreach` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I did read about the foreach function but I think it doesn't suit my case as it needs a fixed list. In my case, the NUM_VARS is not fixed.

Comment: How do you set `NUM_VARS`? Are you using it somewhere else? Would it be possible to change it to a list of numbers instead?

Comment: Yes, I was able to expand it and run a for loop over it. Thanks for suggesting that. My final code looks pretty much like MadScientist's answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude any idea what was wrong with my while loop implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using the shell just for getting the sequence of numbers, like this:

```
NUM_RANGE := $(shell seq 0 $(NUM_VARS))
```

Then you can do this:

```
MYFLAGS += $(foreach N,$(NUM_RANGE),-DMYVAR$N=$(MYVAR$N) )
```

Note the extra space at the end.  There are probably tricksy ways to get `NUM_RANGE` without using `shell` but...

Comment: This seems to do it. Just like suggested by Some Programmer Dude in the comments. Also, this solution feels more readable to me.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers with shell, seq and foreach are excellent and probably good enough for everyone's needs. 
When the use of shell and seq is problematic (e.g. seq is not available), it is easy to generate the sequence just with make:

```
NUM?=3

ENCODE=$(or $(and $(word $(1), $(2)), $(2)), $(call ENCODE, $(1), x $(2) ))
encoded=$(call ENCODE, $(NUM))
$(warning encoded: $(encoded))

GENERATE=$(or $(and $(word $(1), $(2)), $(2)), $(call GENERATE, $(1), $(2) $(words 0 $(2))))
sequence=$(call GENERATE, $(NUM))
$(warning sequence: $(sequence))
```

ENCODE is directly inspired from the encoding used by [GNU Make Standard Library](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) (encoding the number into a sequence of x of the same length). GENERATE has the same result as seq. Both can be improved to add a step, possibly a starting point greater than 1, etc. The resulting variables can be used in a foreach as described in the other answers.

```
y@vb:~$ make NUM=13
Makefile:5: encoded:  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x              
Makefile:9: sequence:               1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NUM := 3
MYFLAGS += $(shell flag=""; for i in $$(seq $(NUM)); do flag=$["$${flag}-DMYVAR$${i}=\$$(MYVAR$${i}) "; done; echo $$flag)

all:
    echo '$(MYFLAGS)'
```

sample output:

```
echo '-DMYVAR1=$(MYVAR1) -DMYVAR2=$(MYVAR2) -DMYVAR3=$(MYVAR3)'
-DMYVAR1=$(MYVAR1) -DMYVAR2=$(MYVAR2) -DMYVAR3=$(MYVAR3)
```

notice the string after echo in the output, the $(MYFLAGS) has been expaned to `-DMYVAR1=$(MYVAR1) -DMYVAR2=$(MYVAR2) -DMYVAR3=$(MYVAR3)`